# How is Quarkus Reactive supposed to work with Panache for Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

I'm trying out Quarkus Reactive + Kotlin, and I seem to have som issues figuring out how the data access part is supposed to work in this case.

Quarkus offers:
quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-kotlin
OR
quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache

There is no quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache-kotlin. It seems I have to choose between Kotlin or reactive functionality. Am I misreading this? And if not, how do people usually solve this problem? Do they select the Panache-Kotlin variant and wrap all repository calls in withContext(Dispatchers.Default) + async? This doesn't feel like an ideal solution. Is there better ways?

Or do people chose the reactive non-kotlin variant, and somehow make that work? Although I have no idea what that would look like.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarkus will provide the `quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache-kotlin` module  starting with Quarkus 2.14.
See [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/25015) for more details

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! Looking forward to the release.